# Where should UICollectionView/UITableView delegate/datasource functions go in Clean Swift [Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture]

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

I recently switched my app over from `MVC` to `Clean Swift` and i'm having trouble deciding in which classes to put certain things.  For example, should the `delegate`/`datasource` functions for a `UICollectionView`/`UITableView` go in the `Interactor`, or `Presenter`?  Or maybe certain functions, like `didSelectItemAt` should go in the `Interactor` because they deal with input, and others, like `cellForItemAt`, should go in the `Presenter` because they deal with views.

What are your decision making processes when deciding where to put certain functionality in `Clean Swift`?`

Currently I have the following in my `ViewController`

```
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)

}
```

the following in my `Interactor`

```
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

and the following in my `Presenter`

```
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, Apple’s built-in protocols with the `UI` prefix should stay in the view controller. If it ever gets too complex, you can simply move the data source and delegate methods to an extension. They rarely gets complicated enough to warrant its own controller. If it does, it means you probably have some business logic there that should be extracted and moved to the interactor. But you should still leave these methods in the view controller or its extension.

Comment: Helpful Article: https://clean-swift.com/vip-cycle-or-property/